# Better approach to Connect TCP Via Http Proxy Server

Tags: c#, tcp, http-proxy

We need to connect our tcp server and make a tcp connection behind the proxy (most firewalls block our direct tcp connection to specific port).

So we implemented Apache http proxy server and connected tcp using HTTP CONNECT METHOD via our http proxy server.

So we need to do the following steps:

- Connect to proxy.
- Send `CONNECT Host:Port HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>`
- Send `<CR><LF>`
- Wait for a line of response. If it contains `HTTP/1.X 200`, the connection is successful
- Read further lines of response until receive an empty line.
- It's connected to the outside world through a proxy

I found below two codes written by someone to accomplish this.

**My question is**: What Is best approach to  make a tcp connection behind a proxy.And which method i should use Webrequest or via TCP Socket?

```
public static class HttpProxy
{
    public static TcpClient connectViaHTTPProxyMethod1(
    string targetHost,
    int targetPort,
    string httpProxyHost, 
    int httpProxyPort,
    string proxyUserName,
    string proxyPassword)
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = null;
        Uri proxyUri = null;
        if (httpProxyHost != "")
        {
            uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
            {
                Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
                Host = httpProxyHost,
                Port = httpProxyPort
            };

            proxyUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            "http://" + targetHost + ":" + targetPort);
        //request.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        var webProxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri);
        if (httpProxyHost != "")
            request.Proxy = webProxy;
        request.Method = "CONNECT";

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            proxyUserName, proxyPassword);

        if (proxyUserName != "")
            webProxy.Credentials = credentials;

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Debug.Assert(responseStream != null);

        const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

        var rsType = responseStream.GetType();
        var connectionProperty = rsType.GetProperty("Connection", Flags);

        var connection = connectionProperty.GetValue(responseStream, null);
        var connectionType = connection.GetType();
        var networkStreamProperty = connectionType.GetProperty("NetworkStream", Flags);

        var networkStream = networkStreamProperty.GetValue(connection, null);
        var nsType = networkStream.GetType();
        var socketProperty = nsType.GetProperty("Socket", Flags);
        var socket = (Socket)socketProperty.GetValue(networkStream, null);

        return new TcpClient { Client = socket };
    }

    public static TcpClient connectViaHTTPProxyMethod2(string targetHost, int targetPort, string httpProxyHost, int httpProxyPort, string proxyUserName, string proxyPassword)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytes;

        // Connect socket
        // Dnt know how to implement proxyUserName proxyPassword
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(httpProxyHost, httpProxyPort);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        // Establish Tcp tunnel
        byte[] tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:{1} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{0}\r\n\r\n", targetHost, targetPort));
        stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
        stream.Flush();

        // Read response to CONNECT request
        bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return client;

    }      
}
```

Comment: *"Is making a tcp connection behind a proxy the best approach?"* - I'm not sure what you are asking. If using the proxy is the only way to get what you want you obviously need to go this way. You don't say any other options you might have. Note though that even this approach will not work in all cases, i.e. some proxies will only allow you to connect to specific ports and some deep inspection devices will block anything which is not TLS or WebSocket inside the CONNECT tunnel.

Comment: i have edited my question. Which method i need to prefer http or tcp ?